# Wireless Access Point with POE capability

Tags: wireless-access-point, power-over-ethernet

Im looking for a decent Wireless Access Point, specifically POE which is small and suitable for used within a residential environment.

Quite a few on the market wouldn't look out of place in an office but i'm looking for something quite discreet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discreet?  How about a [ceiling mount (WAP-3101)](https://adiglobal.us/Pages/Product.aspx?pid=YC-WAP3101&Category=8591_2)?

[image]

The same site lists a more [standard-looking AP (WAP-3100)](https://adiglobal.us/pages/product.aspx?pid=YC-WAP3100&Category=0000), but I'm not sure if that fits your "discreet" requirement.

[image]

This is not to say I recommend these products, just that they might meet your needs.